# Ubuntu 20.04 Battery stuck at estimating and not charging

Tags: 20.04

Battery status keeps showing "estimating" and battery does not charge at all on HP ProBook 640 laptop.

Tried updating to 22.04 as well and same problem persists

Comment: I would try a power reset of the laptop by removing all power, even the battery (if possible) then pressing the power button with no power attached.  If the battery is not removable, power off the system then press and hold the power button for 15-30 seconds then power it back on.

Comment: got a solution?